# (.NET) WCF Service Library doesn't generate code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have followed these steps but in my own implementation for my Smart Device homework

[Walkthrough: Creating an Occasionally Connected Smart Device Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928606%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

but I couldnt get it right so here are my questions:

(1.) I realize after done with Configure Data Synchronization dialog box my visual studio doesn't generate some file with .SyncContract.cs extension. 
Is that a big and serious problem?

(2.) This walkthrough says that there will be service code generated after done with Configure Data Synchronization dialog box, why there's no code generated in my WCF project?

> NorthwindCacheSyncService generated by the Configure Data Synchronization dialog box instead of the default service (Service1) that is generated by the WCF project template.

(3.) Is there any other way to synchronize Smart Device and SQL Server 2005 Express (.mdb file database) without WCF Service Library?